# how to remove array value from array when value not same from both the value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array, and i want to remove **duplicate** record from array2. i don't want to link_id 35 record in array 2 because link_id 35 record is present in array1 so it's not show in array2.

I tried with array_map and Unique methods but it's not working well because i think both the array doesn't have the same value.

```
$array1=

[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [link_id] => 35
            [link_name] => Test Listerine cool mint packets 3 pack
            [alias] => aa
            [link_desc] => 
            [user_id] => 47
            [link_hits] => 103
            [link_votes] => 1
            [link_rating] => 5.000000
            [link_featured] => 0
            [link_published] => 1
            [link_approved] => 1
            [link_template] => 

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [link_id] => 373
            [link_name] => Test Subject Data Collection Fish Fresh Yellow Tail
            [alias] => ba
            [link_desc] =>
            [user_id] => 47
            [link_hits] => 198
            [link_votes] => 8
            [link_rating] => 2.875000
            [link_featured] => 0
            [link_published] => 1
            [link_approved] => 1
            [link_template] => 

        )



$array2 =

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [link_id] => 35
            [link_name] => Test Listerine cool mint packets 3 pack
            [link_desc] => 
            [lat] => 0.000000
            [lng] => 0.000000
            [contactperson] => 
            [cat_name] => AA - Made in USA
            [link_votes] => 1
            [link_rating] => 5.000000
            [link_featured] => 0
            [value] => 30020864
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [link_id] => 541
            [link_name] => Test Subject Data Collection Fish Fresh Yellow Tail
            [link_desc] => 
            [lat] => 25.182573
            [lng] => -80.093079
            [country] => United States
            [postcode] => 33431
            [contactperson] => Captain Jack Certified Charters
            [cat_name] => BA - Product of USA
            [link_votes] => 8
            [link_rating] => 2.875000
            [link_featured] => 0
            [value] => NA
        )
```

Comment: Please include your actual snippet that shows up how far you got with your coding attempt.

Comment: 'code'$result = array_merge($array1,$array2);
$allpage=array();

for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++)
{
 $allpage[] = $result[$i]->link_id;
}

$all_page1 =array_unique($allpage);

$news =array();
$news1 =array();
foreach($result as $val)
{ 
 if (in_array($val->link_id, $all_page1))
 {
  $news[]=$val;
 }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($news1); exit;

Comment: In your question body as an edit please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [array-filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). First extract all the `ids` from the first array and then filter the second array based of those ids.

```
$arr1 = array( (object) ["link_id"=> 35, "key" => "AAA"], (object) ["link_id"=> 373, "key" => "BBB"]);
$arr2 = array( (object) ["link_id"=> 35, "key" => "CCC"], (object) ["link_id"=> 341, "key" => "DDD"]);

$ids = array_column($arr1, "link_id");
$arr2 = array_filter($arr2, function ($e) use ($ids) {
    return !in_array($e->link_id, $ids); //keep him in arr2 only if NOT in ids of arr1
});
```

**Updated more fast answer** Consider big amount of data (as for @mickmackusa comment) use this:

```
$ids = [];
foreach($arr1 as $e)
    $ids[$e->link_id] = true;

$arr2 = array_filter($arr2, function ($e) use ($ids) {
    return !isset($ids[$e->link_id]);
});
```

First solution is in `O(n^2)` and the second is in `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

This should do in php7.

Untested code:

```
var_export(array_diff_key(array_column($array2, null, 'link_id'), array_column($array1, null, 'link_id'));
```

Assign new 1st level keys to both arrays, then filter on those keys.

Checking against keys will be more efficient than making iterated calls of `in_array`.

Comment: Not working this code

Comment: I just updated it, I had the arrays in the wrong order.  If you give me your input arrays as `var_export` I can create a demo.  (I'm not at my computer, my phone slows me down)